# How do I query for monthly page views on a particular page using Google Analytics Data API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is this the right request to send? And then I guess I need to manually sum the metrics over each date in the months? I can't even get the monthly view on the google analytics UI. It only lets me look at weekly. I am using google analytics v4 property. [Docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/basics)

```
POST https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1alpha:runReport
{
  "entity": { "propertyId": "XXXX" },
  "dateRanges": [{ "startDate": "2020-10-01", "endDate": "<today>" }],
  "dimensions": [{ "name": "date" }],
  "metrics": [{ "name": "eventCount" }],
  "dimensionFilter": {
    "andGroup": {
      "expressions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "fieldName": "eventName",
            "stringFilter": {
              "value": "page_view"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "fieldName": "unifiedPageScreen",
            "stringFilter": {
              "value": "www.mysite.com/page_of_interest"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
}
```

How is unifiedPageScreen populated on the page_view event? Do I need to do that manually?

Comment: What is the output that you are receiving with this query? Date-wise event counts?